# Building hadoop mapreduce in Eclipse indigo

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-plugins

I can't compile Hadoop MapReduce on Eclipse. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Which version of Hadoop and how are you building it?

Comment: I use version 0.21.0. I put in the Build Path->Configure Build Path->Builders the following build.xml files: 1)common/build.xml 2)hdfs/build.xml and 3)mapred/build.xml    Thanks!

Comment: Define "can't compile". Just saying something doesn't work isn't helpful.

Comment: I get this error:[ivy:resolve]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 [ivy:resolve]   ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
 [ivy:resolve]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 [ivy:resolve]   :: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-common;0.21.0: not found
 [ivy:resolve]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

Answer (score 0):

Your error log indicates a project dependency issue. Have you tried the steps on Hadoop wiki, especially below commands which generates eclipse .project and .classpath files for you?

```
$ mvn install -DskipTests
$ mvn eclipse:eclipse -DdownloadSources=true -DdownloadJavadocs=true
```

More info on http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowToContribute and http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EclipseEnvironment.